# Are there technical reasons for hiding symbols in a shared library?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dllexport

What's the purpose of hiding symbols in a dll as opposed to just exporting everything? Other than not taking up a little more space in the exe is there any other benefit?

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/yugr/ShlibVisibilityChecker) provides a comprehensive list of advantages for hiding symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any other benefit?

There are *lots* of other benefits.

For the library itself, hidden symbols can not be interposed. When you have code like this in a shared library:

```
int foo() { return 20; }
int bar() { return foo() + 1; }
```

what is the return from `bar`? You might think it's 21, but you may be wrong: if an earlier library defined its own `foo`, the return from `bar` could be *anything*.

Other benefits of symbol hiding include faster symbol resolution time (when the loader looks up `foo`, it has to search each loaded library in turn, and that goes faster if the *exported* set of functions is small), and smaller RAM requirements (since the symbol names are needed by the dynamic loader, they are all present in memory).

Symbol hiding also prevents end users from accidentally depending on library implementation details, allowing you to change the implementation without risk of breaking existing users.

Comment: But that only happens in POSIX right? GetProcAddress would return the right foo. Also, even in Linux there's a flag to not load symbols in the global namespace isn't it so?

Comment: About resolution access time, isn't that a hash map or binsearch? It would be weird if it wasn't.

Comment: @capr The answers to your questions are many and complicated. Yes, `dlopen`ing allows for `RTLD_LOCAL` (but linking directly against a shared library does no). And yes, there are hash tables, but hash tables still need to be searched, and the time to search one is not constant.

Comment: Other benefits: prevent users from accidentally depending on library internals and avoid bugs caused by symbol collisions.

Comment: @yugr Good point; answer updated. The symbol collision is (I think) already covered.

Comment: Maybe I haven't formulated the question very well. My opinion is that this doesn't matter in practice at all really, and I was curious if someone had a different experience. I already knew that a hash map is not O(1).

Comment: @capr It *does* matter in practice *a lot* because symbol name collision (or interpositioning) causes unpredictable results and very hard to track bugs.